# The polymer tutorial app renders a blank page

Tags: polymer

So.. I was trying out the polymer [tutorial](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/tutorial/intro.html) and here's what I followed :-

1) Downloaded the Starter Project

2) ran python -m SimpleHTTPServer after changing directory to starter

Now when I go to localhost:8000 in my browser, a grey page opens up. I tried inspect element and found this error

```
http://localhost:8000/components/platform/platform.js 404 (File not found)
```

Here is a [screenshot](http://imgur.com/KAYYIUv) with the error.

**Addition Info**:

OS : Windows 8.1 Enterprise 32bit

Python: 2.7

Chrome: 35.0.1916.153 m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run python -m SimpleHTTPServer from the top level of the entire project... that would be the ~/polymer-tutorial-master directory. Then go to `http://localhost:8000/starter` to see the starter project. Likewise to see what everything should look like after Step 1, Step 2 and Step 3 you can navigate to `http://localhost:8000/step-1`, etc.

Comment: That's not a stupid mistake. I just did a series of tutorials on another framework that arranged the projects/server instances the way you attempted to run the polymer tuts- so here I am :)

Answer (score 2):

For me, the /starter/index.html was missing the following code in the style block. It's needed for anything to show:

```
  core-header-panel {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; 
  }
  core-toolbar {
    background: #03a9f4;
    color: white;
  }
```